# Voting limits & How to know how many you have left?

Tags: discussion

I'm sorry if this question is vague but basically what I'm chasing is an explanation for how many votes you get in a day.

I found [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that states:

> You can vote 30 times per UTC day, plus 10 more times on questions
>   only.

But I'm uncertain as to if this is on **all** of the following combined:

- Questions
- Answers
- Comments

Or if it's for **just** the answers.

Better yet, is there somewhere were you could get a count (*possibly*) of how many votes you have left for the day?

Comment: [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

Comment: @AzizShaikh Thank you! Had no idea what to search for!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get:

> 30 votes per day +10 for questions only (question-only votes can't be used after 25 votes cast on answers)

and

> 30 comment upvotes/day

Reference: [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

---

Now to your second question:

> is there somewhere were you could get a count (possibly) of how many votes you have left for the day?

When you are close to reaching the limit on post votes, the system will inform you (using on-screen popup message) about how my votes are left for the day. Other option is to go to your profile and check the 'day' votes column in the summary tab.

Currently count of comment votes is not displayed anywhere.